# R: Adding Transposed Matrix to Vector of smaller size gives a variable with the same vector size

Tags: r, machine-learning

I was trying to implement Logarithmic Regression in c++ using some R code. I came across the following code:

```
weights <- c(1, 1)  # repeat this for rerunning the block
learning_rate <- 0.001
for (i in 1:500000){
  prob_vector <- sigmoid(data_matrix %*% weights)
  error <- labels - prob_vector
  weights <- weights + learning_rate * t(data_matrix) %*% error
}
weights
```

I just wanted to ask what is happening in this expression:

```
weights <- weights + learning_rate * t(data_matrix) %*% error
```

Data Matrix is a 800x2 Matrix.
Error Matrix is 800x1.
Weight is 1x2.

I just dont understand how weight is able to be added to by big matrices, and come out being only 1x2.

Comment: Order of operations? (See `?Syntax` for documentation on this) The matrix multiply happens first, so that's a 2x800 multiplied by a 800x1 yielding a 2x1. The remaining operations are vectorized over the matrix and don't change the dimension.

Comment: @joran I misunderstood how matrix multiplication worked, ty for the help